# Mockito Verify variables set in a mock before calling a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to write some unit tests around some legacy code and I'm struggling to work out how to test a piece of code. The pattern is basically:

```
Foo foo = ObjectGetter.getObject(Foo.class);
foo.setVariableX("X");
foo.setVariableY("Y");
foo.performExecute();
//The Foo object has now run some business logic
String bar = foo.getVariableZ();
```

I have mocked the static ObjectGetter class via PowerMock and managed to get pass in a mocked Foo object. What I want to do now is when performExecute is run check that variable X & Y are set to a predetermined value in Foo but not actually run any code in Foo. Then when getVariableZ is called pass back a certain value.

I can get VariableZ passing back whatever I want but I can't work out how to make that a conditional that variable X and Y are set to certain values! I'm using Mockito and PowerMock. Suffice to say I can't change the code I'm testing for various reasons.

Comment: I don't understand. If you're mocking `Foo`, why would you care what it does internally?

Comment: I want to ensure the class this code is running in has passed the correct arguments to Foo otherwise I'm just going to blindly assume it has and potentially miss errors. I don't actually care what it does internally just that it has had the correct arguments passed.

Comment: Then you should be testing `Foo` as a unit, not mocking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to verify that some methods in the mock `foo` were called correctly, you can simply write...

```
Mockito.verify( foo, Mockito.times(1)).setVariableX("x");
```

This will result in a test failure if the method `setVariableX` of the object `foo` was not called exactly once. You cannot really test the variable "x" since it doesn't actually exist in your mock, but you can verify that the setter was called correctly.